# What will be the major product when conjugated alkene (like 1,3-butadiene) is reacted with HBr in presence of R2O2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> What will be the major product when conjugated alkene (like 1,3-butadiene) is reacted with $\ce{HBr}$ in the presence of $\ce{R2O2}$?
>
> [image: 3‐chloro‐4‐ethenyl‐1‐methylcyclohexa‐1,4‐diene + HBr + R2O2]

As we know, two products are formed when no $\ce{R2O2}$ is used because of conjugation in double bond and carbocation. But when $\ce{R2O2}$ is used, free radical is formed.

So, will there be the same case in the following question as well? Also, if answer is yes, then what will be the major product?

Comment: Please convert the image into a better form.. You can use [this](https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/2d-sketcher) to do so.

Comment: The 6-member ring is highly suggestive...